# Fiddler syntax view installation

Tags: 14.04, mono, elementary

I have installed Fiddler 4.4.8.4 using Mono. It works properly. The question is how can I add a syntax view extension.

What I've tried:

- Downloaded installation file for windows and opened it as a archive. Then copied all of the files to Fiddler folder. When I wanted to run Fiddler I got an error message that this extension requires newer version of Fiddler (4.8.*)